# Why allow permission button is disabled?

Tags: contacts, 6.0-marshmallow, permissions

**Problem**

Today I noticed strange behavior on my test phone, which is Nexus 5 with Android  6.0.1.

After opening test app that asks for permission to read contacts `allow` button is not working - after tapping on `allow` nothing happens, but `deny` works perfectly:

[image]

Also when I check `Never Ask Again`, it completely disables `allow` button:

[image]

Not sure what is happening here, but same app works perfectly on my OnePlus2 which uses Android 6.0.1 too.

The only strange thing about my test phone is that it does not have sim card currently.

Note that both phones have Google Account attached with same synchronized contacts.

**Question**

I am wondering what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the stupid [FileManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm) app. Once you stop it or remove it you can allow other apps to access the phone

Comment: This app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm You should probably mention the source. I found this on StackOverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37842758/4583267

Comment: @SuperThomasLab yes that one, it is amazing, but it solved issue.

Comment: I am wondering why it causes the problem, but anyway your answer works. Thank You!

Answer (score -1):

Go to Settings\Apps\Birthday\Permissions and activate Contacts.

Comment: This is a neat idea, but the same screen overlay that stops the allow button working will also stop the permissions menu working.

Comment: Not necessarily.  I had the same problem with another app and this procedure solved it